How to get telegram bot users Count?
So, telegram has launched a new app store on Telegram and I can see no. Of users correposponding to each telegram bot now. Is there a way using Telegram API to fetch this number for a particular bot ? Also, I can't find the documentation or details on how this number is calculated

No. As of now there's no way to get the user count being shown on the Bot's profile.
